# iOS action extension Cocoapods Podfile FBSDKCoreKit 'sharedApplication' is unavailable

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods, podfile

I need the Facebook SDK in both my app and my action extension. I use Cocoapods 1.4.0, Swift 4 and Xcode 9.2. I'm having this error message coming from the `FBSDKCoreKit`:

> 'sharedApplication' is unavailable: not available on iOS (App
>   Extension) - Use view controller based solutions where appropriate
>   instead.

I've already read a lot of answers, on SOF and Github mainly. I tried a lot of suggestions. But I did not make it work.

**My current Podfile:**

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
workspace 'MyApp'
use_frameworks!
platform :ios, '10.0'
inhibit_all_warnings!

def my_pods
    pod 'FBSDKCoreKit'
    pod 'FBSDKLoginKit'
    pod 'FBSDKShareKit'

end

target 'MyApp' do
    my_pods
end

target 'MyAppExtension' do
    my_pods
end
```

**What I tried**:

1) set `Require Only App-Extension-Safe API` to `NO` (both for my app and the extension).

2) add this to my podfile:

```
post_install do |installer_representation|
    installer_representation.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
        if target.name == "Pods-MyAppExtension-FBSDKCoreKit"
            target.build_configurations.each do |config|
                //I tried both these lines
                config.build_settings['GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS'] ||= ['$(inherited)', 'AF_APP_EXTENSIONS=1']
                config.build_settings['APPLICATION_EXTENSION_API_ONLY'] = 'NO'
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: Have you solved the issue? I've the same one :(

Comment: @KostyaVyrodov no I use the static library instead and didn't try again since then.

Comment: I think Facebook has to solve this issue with release new SDK, I have the same issue which SDK conflict with OneSignal extension so far. What I will try ( download old version of FBSDK and send a bug report regarding this issue )

Answer (score 0):

only as documentation if others arrive here:

using SPM and FB SDK 11.0 AND Xcode 12.x it works
using    "          "     AND Xcode 13.beta for iOS13 fails:

'sharedApplication' is unavailable: not available on iOS (App Extension) - Use view controller based solutions where appropriate instead.

PS

it's a shame using objC in 2021... :(

and ridiculous using "SWFT" Package manager containing objC, :(